# list-ref: index too large for list Racket-EOPL

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

I am having a problem using list-ref.

Is there a way to use list-ref to obtain size of an unknown list?

```
 (... (if (number? (deref(+ array-ref index)))
          (array-len array-ref (+ index 1))
  0) )
```

#|(define (deref ref)
  (list-ref the-store ref))
|#

Comment: what's the context of all this, why not use length? there's really no way to a get the length of a list without talking it to the end, as a list is defined as either the empty list or any pair whose cdr is a list. There's nothing at the front to say how long the list is. If you need a list like that consider implementing a finger list.

Comment: This is supposed to be a list called the-store that has some indexes and many references to each index that represent an array.

Comment: Still not clear to me. This is a list of lists? A list of vectors? A list of indices for some given vector of vectors or lists of lists, or mix and match? What exactly is is supposed to look like in the computer?

Comment: @user2227735 the question is not clear. You should edit it and add an _actual_ example, with sample input and the expected output

Answer (score 3):

If you want the *size* of a list use `length`, not `list-ref`. For example, in a list such as this:

```
(define lst '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

… The valid indexes will be between `0` and list's `length` minus one:

```
(list-ref lst 0)
=> 1

(list-ref lst (- (length lst) 1))
=> 5
```

However: in Scheme it's unusual to write code that depends on the *index* of an element in a list, that's how you'd think about a solution in a C-like language using an array, but Scheme lists are different, and normally you traverse a list using recursion - forget about indexes!

Comment: My "array" is in the form store= (index_1 index_2 index_3 ...) and there are many references to each index_1 each index_ith represents an array. So, it can be seen as a two dimensional array. What I really want is the number of references in the index_ith? That's why I call list-ref.

Comment: Apparently you have a list, each member of which is another list? When your `deref` is asked to get something longer than the list length, it needs to return a special value for that condition. What sort of value would be most convenient: `#f`, or `"doesn't exist"`, or `'()` a.k.a. `(list)`, or something else? Would one choice make it easier for `deref` to, let's say, call itself? i.e. Why is your question tagged `recursion`?

Comment: Thanks, I will look a bit more into it. Apparently, I need to use derefence-array and set-array in conjunction.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the list is a list of lists such as:

```
(define lst '((a b c)
              (1 "hi")
              ((lambda(x)(+ 5 x)) 42 'a (14 7 12))
              ("hello" " world")))
```

A quick and dirty way to get the size of an element would be

```
 (define third-of-a-size (third (map length lst)))
```